# Calculating Compound Interest

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate compound interest but I could not be succesfull to write that. How can I fix the code?

Here is my code:

```
def compound_interest(money, lastmoney, rate):
    amountyear=(money*(1+rate//100))//lastmoney
    return amountyear

# store the inputs
money= float(input('money: '))
rate= float(input('Interest rate: '))
lastmoney= float(input('Last money: '))

amountyear= compound_interest(money, lastmoney, rate)
print(amountyear)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We can only help you if you actually *ask a question*, and then only if you have [properly tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to solve it yourself first. "How can I fix the code" [is not a suitable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); it is your responsibility to understand what is wrong and explain why you can't fix it yourself.

Comment: Why do you not use the formula as given in the assignment?

Comment: `P(n+1) = (1+i)P(n)` Looks like it will require a loop or recursion.

Comment: You should start by trying to understand the problem. For example, you quote from the assignment: `For instance: P(0)=1000 i=0.05 and goal=2000 should return 15 P(0)=1000 i=0.07 and goal=2000 should return 11`. **Why**? Why is the answer 11, and not any other number? Show me the steps that you would take, with paper and pencil, in order to calculate that.

Comment: just use the formula? sth like `return p * (1 + r / n) ** (n * t)`

Comment: I could not find the solution with this formula.Which method should I use with the formula that is given in the question?Could you show me that?@ Johnny Mopp

Comment: I am gonna try that again.@ Matiiss

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: As an aside, you can see if your answer is in the right ballpark with the 'rule of 70'. With an interest rate of 5% your money doubles in roughly 70/5 = 14 years etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula `P(n+1) = (1+i)P(n)` should give you a hint that either a loop or recursion is needed. Here's a recursive example:

```
def compound_interest(p0, i, goal):
  # Goal is reached - end recursion
  if p0 >= goal: return 0
  # Compute interest
  p0 += p0 * i
  # Call recursively. The +1 is adding one year to result
  return compound_interest(p0, i, goal) + 1

print(compound_interest(1000, 0.05, 2000))
print(compound_interest(1000, 0.07, 2000))
```

Outputs:

```
15
11
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It compiled.@Johnny Mopp

Answer (score 2):

Using some math (solving for `amountyears`, see below), you can use the resulting formula to get your result.

```python
import math


def compound_interest(money, lastmoney, rate):
    amountyear = math.log(lastmoney / money) / math.log(rate + 1)
    return amountyear


# store the inputs
money = float(input('money: '))
rate = float(input('Interest rate: '))
lastmoney = float(input('Last money: '))

amountyear = compound_interest(money, lastmoney, rate)
print("exact: ", amountyear)  # 14.206699082890463
print("rounded to next year: ", math.ceil(amountyear))  # 15
```

Math:

[image: Solving for n]

Comment: This is probably the most correct answer. Everyone else (including me!) just assumed that OP was not interested in non-integer answers :-P

Answer (score 0):

A non-recursive answer:

```
def n_years(P0, i, goal):
    n = 0
    running_total = P0
    while (running_total < goal):
        n += 1                    # equivalent to n = n + 1
        running_total *= (1 + i)  # equivalent to running_total = running_total * (1 + i)
    return n

n_years(1000, 0.07, 2000) # 11
n_years(1000, 0.05, 2000) # 15
```

Note that the variable running_total isn't necessary: I used it to make the code more legible.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import log,ceil

def YearsToGoal(start,goal,interest):
    fExact = (log(goal)-log(start))/log(1+interest)
    return ceil(fExact)
```